# Си: как правильно говорить поле структуры или элемент структуры?

Tags: c, терминология

В русскоязычной литературе очень часто встречается "поле структуры". В K&R в оригинале написано "member", в русском переводе - "поле". Но ведь "поле" - это "field". Однажды задавал вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow, написал "field" - меня поправили. Получается, что авторы многих наших книг ошибаются?

Comment: В литературе 90-х эти элементы переводились как есть, то есть Член-переменная/Переменная член объекта класса, или функция-член ... Корявенько, поэтому перешли на Поле и просто функцию

Comment: "авторы многих наших книг ошибаются" - это еще как-то можно было бы утверждать, если бы они писали по-английски :) А так... Не к этому конкретному случаю, но есть варианты, когда очень трудно перевести однозначно и верно - например, template и pattern, или speed и velocity в физике - как не крути, а у нас устоялся один термин для обоих понятий. Или как вы переведете blue - синий или голубой? :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin функция-член, член-данное - это как раз официальные термины C++ (точнее, более точные переводы), а поле и метод - это общие названия из ООП.

Comment: @Croessmah спасибо кэп. Лично мне все понятно как не назови, главное, чтобы автор вопроса понял

Answer (score 2):

Поле это устоявшийся термин в программировании. В англоязычной литературе также можно встретить `class field`. `class member` это более широкий термин, включающий в себя поля, методы и всё, что относится к классу(структуре). Учитывая, что в C у структур нет методов, то термины `field` и `member` равнозначны.

Comment: но за structure field англичане на меня ругались. Видимо по-английски все-таки правильно говорить structure member, как в книжках написано, а по-русски - поле или элемент.

Comment: @user490334, по-английский правильно говорить именно member, потому что это «официальный» термин из стандарта языка. Устоявшегося русского перевода нет, поэтому по-русски можете говорить как вам нравится.

Comment: нельзя говорить " как вам нравится". давайте тогда называть "штучкой" или "пимпочкой". может кому то так нравится.

Comment: @KoVadim, не надо передергивать мои слова. Речь шла о выборе между «поле структуры», «элемент структуры» и «член структуры».

Comment: как по мне, то поле структуры уже звучит неверно, где то как мокрая вода.

Answer (score 1):

В стандарте языка C (текущий от 2018 года) слово "field" упоминается только в двух контекстах:

- для битовых полей (bit-field);
- при задании ширины форматированного ввода/вывода (field width).

Единственным правильным (оригинальным термином) для членов структуры является "member". В частности можно встретить такие упоминания:

- 1023 **members** in a single structure or union // 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
- ```
  struct {
     char a;
     int b:5, c:11,:0, d:8;
     struct {int ee:8;} e;
  }
  ```

  The **member** a, and bit-fields d and e.ee are each separate memory locations
- An identifer can denote an object; a function; a tag or a **member** of a structure, union, or enumeration ... // 6.2.1 Scopes of identifers

Ну и основное это, наверное, вот:

- A structure type describes a sequentially allocated non empty set of **member** objects (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplet earray), each of which has an optionally specifed name // 6.2.5 Types p.20
  andpossiblydistincttype.